# Frobenius method for solving differential equations (heat dissipation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have one question regarding the Frobenius method. Beforehand, though, I would like to point out that I have already asked in Mathematics section and got no response what so ever.
I have been solving a differential equation regarding heat dissipation, and without going into further detail I came across a problem since I am not mathematically well versed (theoretical physics is not my strong suite).
The question is: When you want to represent an equation using Frobenius method for power series, do you have to shift all the powers of $x^{n+\lambda}$,
[where $n=1, 2, 3...\infty$ and $\lambda$ is/are the root/s of the indicial polynomial]
to the lowest power?
ex.
$a_0*...*[\sum_{0}^{\infty}x^{n+\lambda} + \sum_{0}^{\infty}x^{n+\lambda + 1} + \sum_{0}^{\infty}x^{n+\lambda-1}]$

Do I have to shift everything to $x^{n+\lambda-1}$  (lowest power) or can I shift it to $x^{n+\lambda+1}$ (highest power)
so that I get $a_0*...*x^{n+\lambda+1}*[ \sum...]$
or will shifting to the highest power mess up my indicial equation?
Summa summarum, is there any difference in shifting the power upwards rather than downwards when solving a differential equation using power series (Frobenius)

EDIT: I want to get the following: $a_0x^{\lambda + 1}[(\lambda +1)(\lambda)+...]*x^{n+\lambda+1}[\sum...]$ $->$
indicial equation $*$ power series

Comment: As far as I remember, you have the freedom to chose one way or another. Final result will be different, but linearly dependent - of course. Learning for Mathematical Physics course? :) I remember Sunko as excellent professor.

Comment: Ivica Smolić is now running the show, Sunko is in Statistical Physics. Cheers frende.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: As I have already said, I've asked and got no response whatsoever

Comment: Everything will be easier to follow if you write the equation you're trying to solve.